# Bug in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a problem that happen eventually: certain features of Visual Studio 2012 stop working. For example, I can't write numbers in the zoom tool (image 1), it only works by selecting the default options. I can't use "control" + "scroll wheel" in the design window to change the zoom. And in the Properties window (image 2) I can't filter properties, it is impossible to write in the filter field as shown in image 3.

When I restart the program, it returns to running everything normal, but at a certain point it happens again. I do not understand what action is the beginning of the problem.

Visual Studio version: Ultimate 2012
Running on Windows 7 Ultimate x64

[image: Zoom tool]

[image: Property window]

[image: Filtered property window]

Comment: The XAML editor is a Greek tragedy.  Particularly in VS2012, adapting it to also support WinRT apps did not go well, it was *very* late to get stable in beta.   Only real defense you have is to edit the XAML directly, like most programmers do, and keeping your VS version updated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it looks like a bug.. you might want to try out Visual Studio 2015.

Or you might want to report this @ https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio